# Clear default text from <p> tag when clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mw4c/12/

I would like to be able to clear the text from the `<p>` tag, and begin to start typing. The problem I am having is that when you click, the `<p>` tag gets cleared, and I can't type in it.

**JavaScript:**

```
$("p").on("mousedown", function(e){
    if($(this).text() === "Click"){
        $(this).text("").focus();
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content" contenteditable="true"><p>Click</p></div>
```

What do I need to be able to do to start writing in the tag?

Comment: For what its worth, this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiattp/2mw4c/11/) does a similar thing (borrowed from my answer to your previous question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve, but it worked for me when I moved the `contenteditable` to the `p` element.

The impression I'm getting from your comments is that you want to keep the current structure in your markup. It seems that the `div` is collapsing due to the `p` being empty. I've updated my fiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/nyaray/2UJRS/2/

Comment: @RyanNaddy then you could select it by ID (that you'd have to assign to the element) or, if a parent that's close enough has an ID, use a more elaborate selector when targeting the element.

Comment: Actually... you could use a class as well, for example, if you intend to have multiple editing panes visible at the same time.

Comment: Actually that edit is false, without `contenteditable` on the `p` tags, I can still edit them.

Comment: Whoop, my bad. So, does that mean that you just need to keep things from collapsing due to them being empty?

Answer (score 1):

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/2mw4c/24/)

```
$("p").on("mousedown", function (e) {
    var that = $(this);
    var txt = that.text();
    if (txt === "Click") {
        height = that.css('height');
        that.css('height', height).text("").focus();
    } else if ((txt).length) {
        that.css('height', 'inherit');
    } else if (txt.length === 0) {
        that.css('height', height);
    }
});
```

Comment: I like it, I am not too fond of the height as an inline style, but I think I can deal with it.

Comment: @RyanNaddy Welcome  :) yeah you can use a class instead of inline style .

Answer (score 1):

You can set a minimum height and width. You need to specify the size or else, there will be no clickable area inside the p-tag since in is an inline element.

http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/WZg6H/

```
div.content>p {
    min-width: 1em;
    min-height: 1em;
    background: #EEF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the tag `<p>` you are trying is to use as input so please check the following change:

Try this instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/2mw4c/22/